# Adding Network Location to Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, nfs, shared-folders

This issue sounds to be simple, however after spending some hours over the internet with no results, it is not.

I need to add NFS to windows server 2012 r2, so it can be used for backups. while trying to `add a network location` it did not accept files using IP address, giving following error:

[image]

while when trying to add the remote server to the network devices so it become accessible, I couldn't find the option that let me add the device via its IP address, also it is not listed within network devices.

any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows servers can not mount nfs shares by default. You have to install the feature "Client for NFS" in the Server Manager.

After that you should be able to mount nfs shares via:

```
mount -user:youruser -p:yourpassword \\yournfsserver\yourpath\toshare Z:
```

Comment: I should replace yournfsserver with its IP address?

Comment: IP address or hostname if DNS is working